# Accept 2xx in sipp

Tags: sip

Is it possible to accept multiple responses in sipp (http://sipp.sourceforge.net/)?
From the server I can expect either 202 or 200 Ok as response
For that I use

```
<recv response="200" rtd="true">
    </recv>
```

How to write sipp xml file, in such a way that it accepts both 200 and 202

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this by setting one of the responses as optional and, by using a label, jump jump following response. Something like:

```
<recv response="202" optional="true" next="3">
  ... Do something ...
</recv>

<recv response="200" rtd="true">
</recv>

<label id="3" />
```

With this, if you receive a 202 response, you do something and follow at label "3". On the other hand, if you receive a 200 OK response, 202 is optional, so the scenario will continue properly.